# how to load from network when only new data available using volley

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I am in a project and using volley to parse data from internet. I have successfully cached the data and can retrieve the data from there and if cache is not available then parse from network by the following code:

```
Cache cache = GlobalData.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Entry entry = cache
                .get("http://10.10.10.22/emaildata/getcurrentuser.php");
        if (entry != null) {
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);
                setParsedValue(array);


            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {


            JsonArrayRequest jArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    "http://10.10.10.22/emaildata/getcurrentuser.php",
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray array) {

                            setParsedValue(array);

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();

                        }
                    });

            GlobalData.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArrayRequest);

        }
```

now I want that the data will always load from the cache until new data is available on that network url, as far I did is the following on `onPause();`

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        GlobalData
                .getInstance()
                .getRequestQueue()
                .getCache()
                .invalidate("http://10.10.10.22/emaildata/getcurrentuser.php",
                        true);
    }
```

sometimes it works but sometimes it doesnt work, most of the time I had to restart my device to get awared about the new data where I want instead, can anyone help how to instantly get the data changes to parse from the network or load from the cache otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

> I am in a project and using volley to parse data from internet. I have
> successfully cached the data and can retrieve the data from there and
> if cache is not available then parse from network by the following
> code:
>
> ...
>
> now I want that the data will always load from the cache until new
> data is available on that network url
>
> ...
>
> can anyone help how to instantly get the data changes to parse from the network or load from the cache otherwise?

Volley dose all of above task automatically as long as the server response allows it, for example dose not have any field like:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache|no-store
```

which cause Volley dose not store the response.

all you have to do is just making request. if it is in his cache and it is valid (max-age or ttl or... is ok) it returns that for you else if it is expired or it is not valid anymore it creates new request.

Comment: I have made request and loaded data, then I pressed back and got out of my app, then I have made a change on my url json after that when I entered in my app again the new changes were not updated, when I force stop the app or restart my device then the data update receives. But I want that instantly like when I first run the app after the data changes the data should be updated on the app too.

Comment: at `onResume()` create new volley request. and I hope you now how to update widgets for example notifyDataSetChanged() for listview or ...

Comment: can u give me an example? I just want that solution

Answer (score -1):

If you want to ensure that you always get fresh data from the server instead of locally cached you can append a current timestamp to your url call. This will ensure that Volley treats the url you pass it as unique and therefore it will make a request to the server.

e.g.

```
int time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis());
JsonArrayRequest jArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                "http://10.10.10.22/emaildata/getcurrentuser.php?time"
```